# Netlogo ticks as a counter for a race

Tags: netlogo

I'm writing code to make a race between 5 turtles. I have to show who wins the race through the use of ticks. I think I can use the ticks to count how much time it takes each turtle to move then compare them. However, I can't figure out where to put the "tick" in my code. Here's my code:

```
    to finish
ask patches 
   ;sets finish line pattern
[ifelse (pxcor + pycor) mod 2 = 0 
   ;if true do this
[set pcolor pink]
   ;if false do this
[set pcolor yellow]
]

  ask patches 
   ;sets background black other than the finish line
 [if pxcor < 12 [set pcolor black]
 ]
 end
 to lanes
  ask patches
   ;sets the lanes
  [ if pycor = 3 and pxcor < 12 [set pcolor white] 
  if pycor = 9 and pxcor < 12 [set pcolor white] 
  if pycor = -3 and pxcor < 12 [set pcolor white] 
  if pycor = -9 and pxcor < 12 [set pcolor white] ]
   ;setup for the turtle positions
 cro 5
 ask turtle 0 [setxy -15 0]
 ask turtle 1 [setxy -15 6]
 ask turtle 2 [setxy -15 12]
 ask turtle 3 [setxy -15 -6]
 ask turtle 4 [setxy -15 -12]
 ask turtles [set heading 90] ;set heading 90 means moving the head of the    turtle right 90 degrees
 reset-ticks
end 

to setup
 finish
 lanes
end

to movecars
every .1 
[fd random 10 / 10]
end

to endrace
 movecars
if xcor >= 12 [die]
end

to go
endrace
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost always, `tick` goes as the last command in the go procedure. Certainly that's what you should be doing while you are new to NetLogo. Having said that, it won't make your code work.

Think of ticks as a time step counter. Each loop through the go procedure should do all the actions that need one time step to do and also advances the time step counter. So you don't need the `every` command, you just have the movecars procedure called by the go procedure and have `ask turtles [forward random 10 / 10]` in the movecars procedure.

This is a fairly fundamental conceptual gap and I suggest you look through some of the models in the NetLogo models library, focusing on the link between the go procedure and the moving procedure and the passage of time. Or perhaps do the tutorials again. Also, start your model more simply. Just create one car and get it to move, then worry about multiple cars, colours and seeing who wins. Add a little piece of your model and make it work before adding the next piece.

Try this:

```
to go
  movecars
  endrace
  tick
end

to movecars
  ask turtles [ fd random 10 / 10]
end

to endrace
  ask turtles [ if xcor >= 12 [die] ]
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I removed the every command and added the "ask turtles" however, I am unable to run the program, it says "Only the observer can ASK the set of all turtles.
error while turtle 1 running ASK
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'go'"                                                                                                  I tried to reset the agent to turtles, but it says that the procedure can only be run with observer?

Comment: This is a really subtle error. Because you have the endrace procedure starting with if xcor, NetLogo is treating this as a turtle context procedure. So, you would have the procedure that calls it do something like `ask turtles [endrace]`. This means that you effectively have `ask turtles [ ask turtles [do something]]` which generates the error.. In my revised code, you will see that I also did ask turtles in the endrace procedure and that explicitly switches contexts and returns to the observer at the end of the code block

Comment: Thank you for your help!